# Cost of usage for various providers

Tags: google-maps, maps, bing-maps, geolocation, mapquest

I want to use maping services in my website and I am confused about the options that are provided. I try to do a comparision between features, accuracy and most important cost.

I am total newbie and I keep reading and searching but I can't find a definite answer. From what I managed to collect so far there are 4 major players providing Javascript API. Google, Bing, Yahoo and MapQuest. I believe that in order to use them for comercial use I must purchase an enterprise license. Unfortunately the cost is unknown and nowhere can be found definite numbers in dollars without contacting them.

From what I managed to find it seems that Google costs $10.000 per year while MapQuest around $2500. But I could not find anything about Bing and Yahoo.

So, roughly, how much each provider charges for enterprise usage of their maps?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is limited in time (prices may not be accurate in 6 months to a year) and also information should be requested from the service providers.

Comment: I kind of like it. It could be worded better to fit but has definitive answers as of today and is of interest to the wider GIS community.

Answer (score 0):

OSM has a very powerful [API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API) and the cost is $0.00 per year and $0.00 per year after that.

Enterprise use is the same cost.

Do you mean ESRI Javascript API? If not you missed ESRI.

Comment: Unfortunately I need geocoding and Nominatim is not acurate at all. I provide in this page http://www.gisgraphy.com/compare/ the city name and postal code and it returns address in other irrelevant country. Even MapQuest return address in the US while I choose European country.

Comment: No mention of this in the question. Please ask a new question and the new question is better suited to this site anyway. Your question asks about enterprise cost of usage for maps not any process you desire a level of accuracy to utilize the product. For what you require Navteq may be the best option but you do not tell us the geocoding part. May I suggest if Mapquest is providing US returns for EU queries then you may not be using standard inout formats.